# Plot csv file graph using Qt Creator

Tags: linux, qt, csv

I am working with Qt Creator and I am completely new to it.

How can I plot a graph in Qt Creator?

I have a csv file which has some data stored in  it. I want all the rows to be added so that they become a single row and plot that row in the graph as my data is continuously updated so I cannot add the all rows and store it in thee next row.

Answer (score 0):

You aren't really using Qt creator - that's the gui editor for Qt's gui markup language.

The easiest way to plot a graph in Qt is to use the [qwt](http://qwt.sourceforge.net/) widget set

Comment: sorry sir i didnt get you and please sir tell me how to get that qwt widget

Comment: The download link suggests it's only available with svn -the javascript answer above, or for simple graphs just drawing into a qpainter may be easier

Answer (score 0):

in my opinion the best way currently would be to

1. generate html document that plots your graph using FLOTR JS library
   look -> http://solutoire.com/flotr/
   This library gives much better looking results then QWT. You could also generate text reports mixed with graphs.
2. display this html document inside your form using QtWebKit (internal Qt www browser)